# Python.h missing in Blender Python?

Tags: python

I'm compiling an external C package for my Blender  2.78a Python 3.5.

My compiling script looks like

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
import numpy
setup(name='_tifffile', ext_modules=[Extension('_tifffile', ['tifffile.c'], include_dirs=[n
umpy.get_include()])])
```

Upon running it, I got

```
tifffile.c:71:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 #include "Python.h"
                    ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I looked into `/blender-2.78a-linux-glibc211-x86_64/2.78/python/include/python3.5m/` and indeed didn't see `Python.h`.

In general Python community, [people suggest simply uninstalling the current Python and reinstalling the `dev` version.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11094752/2106753) I don't wanna hack the Python bundled with Blender like that.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I realize this is actually a frequently occurring problem. In the past 10 days, while I was using Blender Python's `pip` to install modules, I had this problem twice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**First**, if you install blender with your linux distro,
then a proper installation of python3 and blender with your particular distro should solve your problem.

e.g. for debian:

1. `sudo apt-get install python3 python3-dev`
2. `sudo apt-get install blender`

**Second**, if you really want to install the python header files
for the python that runs inside blender, then you can do it the following way:

Find out the exact blender python version:

1. `/path/to/blender-2.78a-linux-glibc211-x86_64/2.78/python/bin/python3.5m -V`

Download and install the python header files from the official python homepage:

1. point your browser at https://www.python.org/downloads/source/
2. download Gzipped source tarball from the *exact same* python version as your blender python version
3. `cd ~/Downloads/`
4. `tar -xzf Python-3.X.X.tgz`
5. `cp Python-3.X.X/Include/* /path/to/blender-2.78a-linux-glibc211-x86_64/2.78/python/include/python3.5m/`

That should get you rolling. 
Best, Bue

Comment: I went with Option #2, and it was awesome. Thanks!

Comment: @SibbsGambling :' ). Tnx!

Comment: I'm also trying option #2, but I'm getting an error from `cp` saying that the location is read only (so it can't copy in). I've installed Blender using snap. Please let me know how this can be resolved!

Comment: hi @Microbob !
Try: `chmod +w -R /path/to/blender-2.78a-linux-glibc211-x86_64/2.78/python/include/python3.5m/`
but be **VERY CAREFUL** with this command that you only execute it on this particular folder. It is easy to mess up your whole operating system installation if you for example execute this command on your root folder.
Actually, before you do this you should read about the unix command chmod and chow  that you at least a little bit know what's going on! here are the links:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chown

Comment: Actually, you said, you installed blender installed with **snap**.
I have not experiences snap, but as far as I understand, snap is similar to flatpak makes a container around each installation. Could you find your /path/to/blender-2.78a-linux-glibc211-x86_64 ?
I think this whole thing will not work with a snap installation because you have to find a way into the container, and I doubt that you did.

Comment: Yeah I tried using chmod on the snap install of Blender, but it didn’t work. I’ve ended up just installing a matching Python from source instead. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Microbob , maybe, if you have used chmod on your whole blender snap installation, you should uninstall and install blender, just to get it airtight again.

Comment: Yeah I switched it back to be safe. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I tried your second approach, but still getting the same error. Any idea why it is still not loading? Trying to install GDAL

Answer (score 1):

You have to install the Python development package. In Ubuntu is `python3-dev` (if you are using Python3). So:

> sudo apt install python3-dev

Comment: I'm talking about the python bundled with Blender.

Comment: Have you tried to install the version of Python you need with dev tools in a custom directory and make the Blender path to point to it then? I don't see how the Python version bundled with Blender can be different from the standard library, assuming they are the same version

Comment: How does one " make the Blender path to point to it"? It would be great if this actually is possible. Thanks

Comment: Try set environment variables properly: https://www.blender.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=25657